# confused by unit testing and Mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mocking, mockito

I'm new to unit test and Mockito. I got confused by what I should test and verify. I have a class A as follows:

```
public class A{
    @Autowired
    private B b;

    public double doSomething(Request r){
        r = b.process1(r);
        r = b.process2(r);
        return calculateFinal(r);
    }

    public void reportSomething(Request r){
        r = b.process1(r);
        r = b.process2(r);
        b.report(r);
    }

    private int calculateFinal(Request r){
        return r.getFinalScore() * 2;
    }
}
```

Suppose I want to test these two methods with Junit test. Since I have a dependency B in A, I mock it with Mockito. For both tests, I was told that I should assume that the dependency b is fully tested and properly working since we want to test the business logic in A.

At first it looks like that I don't have to test anything for `reportSomething()` since it only involves calls to `b` and they are all "working"? The only thing I can think of to test is whether they are actually called and the order of the calls, correct? So should I just call a.reportSomething() and then do the verification? One thing that bugs me is that whether I should stub the b.process1() and b.process2() to return anything. I tried without stubbing anything and it worked, but why?

For testDoSomething(), I think what I'm really testing is the calculateFinal() method. But since it uses the data from the Request object, I need to set that data in Request `r` first. Since `r` directly comes from `b.process2()`, I should stub the method call to return a Request object with that data. But I could skip the stubbing of `b.process1()`, right?

Is this a right thinking process? Did I miss something or misunderstand something? If it's right, is there a better and cleaner way to write it? Thank you!

```
public class ATest{
    private static final int SCORE = 100;

    @Mock
    private B mockB;

    @InjectMocks
    private A aClient;

    @Before
    public void setUpTest{
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void testReportSomething(){
        // what should I test here?

        Request r = new Request();

        // is it necessary to include the following two lines?
        when(mockB.process1(any(Request.class))).return(r);
        when(mockB.process2(any(Request.class))).return(r);


        aClient.reportSomething(r);
        InOrder inOrder = inOrder(mockProcesser);
        inOrder.verify(mockProcesser).process1(any(Request.class));
        inOrder.verify(mockProcesser).process2(any(Request.class));
        inOrder.verify(mockProcesser).report(any(Request.class));
    }

    @Test
    public void testDoSomething(){
        // Is this correct?
        Request r = new Request();
        r.setFinal(SCORE);

        // I skipped this line and it still works
        when(mockB.process1(any(Request.class))).return(r);

        when(mockB.process2(any(Request.class))).return(r);
        assert(SCORE * 2, aClient.doSomething(r));
        // is it still necessary to verify the call to mockB?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are doing your test incorrectly. Let's look at the method you want to test:

```
public void reportSomething(Request r){
    r = b.process1(r);
    r = b.process2(r);
    b.report(r);
}
```

First of all, you need to mock that when b processes a request, it returns the expected result; DO NOT therefore use the same return value for two invocations.

Here is how I would write the test:

```
final Request r = mock(Request.class);
final Request r1 = mock(Request.class);
final Request r2 = mock(Request.class);

when(mockB.process1(r)).thenReturn(r1);
when(mockB.process2(r1)).thenReturn(r2);
doNothing().when(mockB).report(any(Request.class));

final InOrder inOrder = inOrder(mockB);

// Launch... And then verify:

inOrder.verify(mockB).process1(r);
inOrder.verify(mockB).process2(r1);
inOrder.verify(mockB).report(r2);
inOrder.verifyNoMoreInteractions();
```

As to:

> ```
>   // is it necessary to include the following two lines?
> ```

Yes. By default, when unspecified, a mocked instance will return Java's defaults: 0 for numeric primitives, false for boolean, null for objects. You MUST specify what you want to be returned by stubbing.

Comment: So even though that we know the dependency b works properly, we still need to mock it by "when b processes a request, it returns the expected result"? Also, why `doNothing().when(mockB).report(any(Request.class));` but not `doNothing().when(mockB).report(r2);`? Thanks.

Comment: `b` may work properly but here you don't test `b`; as do the second point, it is to broaden the scope of the stub. It is verifications which matter, and you want to test that `b.report()` was called with `r2`.

Comment: On a side note, I would add that testing once the code is done is usually a lot trickier as the code is a lot less test friendly. If mocks are needed this becomes even more delicate without refactoring.